# RDLC not updating or not being replaced on click-once installation

Tags: rdlc, appdata

I have a click-once application which has an RDLC file, users recently discovered that the are some instances where a blank page get inserted at the top of the pdf file produced by the app(via rdlc of course), then I found out that cause of the issue is an extra spaces that were found between two of the text-boxes on the RDLC.

I closed the spaces, tested and visual studio and all works fine. I deployed to QA environment, however upon testing I realized that the blank page is still there, I then copied the RDLC file from the visual studio to the contect folder in the C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0 and it worked perfectly, no blank page. To me it looks like the RDLC does not get updated when a new version of the app is installed.

The **Copy to Output Director**y property of the rdlc file in VS is set to **Copy always** and the **Build Action** is set to **Content**

What could be the problem here, please assist.

Comment: what is the Build Action of the file?

Comment: It is set to Content, I have also included it n the question so to make it easy for the next person trying to answer the question

Comment: Is it listed in the 'application files' dialog, and if so, how?